# Installing OpenWRT

Tags: router, wireless-networking, openwrt

I'm a complete networking beginner, trying to install OpenWRT on a TPLink 703N, following these instructions : http://wiki.xinchejian.com/wiki/Install_OpenWRT_on_TPlink_WR703N

Having installed and OpenWRT and configured it as outlined on that page, we're trying to see the internet from it (in order to run opkg etc). We have the TPLink connected to our router/modem via ethernet cable and can ssh to it from the other machines on the same network.

However we can't 
a) see the TPLink itself as a wifi router. (Doesn't look like wifi is currently enabled)
b) see the internet from inside it (to run opkg etc.)

Can anyone give some clues (in fairly layman's language) of how to debug this? What kind of problems should we look for? And how should we resolve them?

/etc/config/network

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'wlan0'
    option proto 'dhcp'
```

/etc/config/wireless

```
config wifi-device  radio0
    option type     mac80211
    option channel  11
    option hwmode   11ng
    option path 'platform/ar933x_wmac'
    option htmode   HT20
    list ht_capab   SHORT-GI-20
    list ht_capab   SHORT-GI-40
    list ht_capab   RX-STBC1
    list ht_capab   DSSS_CCK-40
    # REMOVE THIS LINE TO ENABLE WIFI:
    #option disabled 1

config wifi-iface
    option device   radio0
    #option network  lan
    option network  wan
    #option mode     ap
    option mode     sta
    option ssid     'THE NAME OF OUR EXISTING WIFI NETWORK'
    #option encryption none
    option encryption wep+shared
    option key 'WEP PASSWORD FOR OUR EXISTING WIFI NETWORK'
```

cheers

phil

Comment: Show enabled network interfaces with `ip link` and see your wifi settings with `iwconfig wlan0` or `iw -i wlan0 status`. For debugging purpose there are logs in `cat /var/log/messages | more` and `cat /var/log/syslog | more` (not sure if this one is in openwrt)

Answer (score 1):

For your wireless issues, if we look at your wireless configuration:

```
config wifi-iface
    option device   radio0
    #option network  lan
    option network  wan
    #option mode     ap
    option mode     sta
    option ssid     'THE NAME OF OUR EXISTING WIFI NETWORK'
    #option encryption none
    option encryption wep+shared
    option key 'WEP PASSWORD FOR OUR EXISTING WIFI NETWORK'
```

You have the mode `ap` line commented out and replaced with the `sta` option. According to the [OpenWRT documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless), this means that the wireless interface is configured for client mode. With the other options you have in place, your device is configured to act as a client device and connect to your existing network. Because if this, it can't function as an access point.

If you're device is connecting to your network via the wireless interface, why do you have a Ethernet cable connected to your LAN?

I do not see where you note your DNS servers. This might be the cause of why the device can't 'access' the internet to get packages from opkg. You may check to see what the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is, since it lists what name servers the device uses for DNS name resolution.

An example (using Google's name servers):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

You can also try adding the following to `/etc/config/network`:

`option dns    8.8.8.8`

Hope this helps...

### **EDIT**

Here is a suggested configuration for the wifi interface for using it as an access point:

```
config wifi-iface
    option device     radio0
    option network    lan
    option mode       ap
    option ssid       'DESIRED SSID HERE'
    option encryption wep+shared
    option key        'YOUR WEP PASSWORD FOR ACCESS'
```

You want `network` set to `lan` and `mode` set to `ap`. I highly recommend some form of encryption and would suggest you use something other than WEP because it's insecure.

Comment: Thanks. The DNS tip got us on to the internet so we could download opkg and the browser-UI which let us set up the rest of the parameters. Unfortunately, although we can now see the router via wifi, it still doesn't seem to let us connect to it with wifi.

Comment: currently : 
config wifi-device 'radio0'
        option type 'mac80211'
        option channel '11'
        option hwmode '11ng'
        option path 'platform/ar933x_wmac'
        option htmode 'HT20'
        list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-20'
        list ht_capab 'SHORT-GI-40'
        list ht_capab 'RX-STBC1'
        list ht_capab 'DSSS_CCK-40'
        option txpower '27'
        option country 'GB'

config wifi-iface
        option device 'radio0'
        option key 'KEY'
        option ssid 'NETWORK'
        option network 'wan'
        option encryption 'none'
        option mode 'ap'

Comment: Anything in the above list look strange?

Comment: @interstar See updated answer.